# VS 2015 Regex find and replace

Tags: regex, visual-studio, visual-studio-2015

Is there a way to find
`public int MyOldId {get; set;}`
and replace for
`public Guid MyOldUId {get; set;}
 public int MyOldId {get; set;}`
?

Details:
Yes, repeat whats already there adding a *U* and changing type

Comment: Didn't `public int MyOldId {get; set;}` search and `public Guid MyOldUId {get; set;}\npublic int MyOldId {get; set;}` replacement work?

Comment: No because i don't know the Name of the property that is already there... all i know is that it ends with a capital 'i' and a regular 'd'

Comment: Try `public\s+int\s+(\w+)Id\s*{get;\s*set;\s*}` and replace with `public Guid $1UId {get; set;}\r\n$&`, see [this demo](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=public%5cs%2bint%5cs%2b%28%5cw%2b%29Id%5cs*%7bget%3b%5cs*set%3b%5cs*%7d&i=public+int+MyOldId+%7bget%3b+set%3b%7d&r=public+Guid+%241UId+%7bget%3b+set%3b%7d%0d%0a%24%26) (*Context* tab)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just checked and I believe you can use

```
public\s+int\s+(\w+)Id\s*{\s*get;\s*set;\s*}
```

and replace with

```
public Guid $1UId {get; set;}\r\n$&
```

The `(\w+)Id` matches and captures into Group 1 one or more word chars (letters/digits/underscores) before matching `Id`, `\s*` matches zero or more whitespaces (when they may be present or absent).

The replacement pattern uses the backreference to Group 1 contents (`$1`) and the `$&` refers (inserts to the result) the whole match found with the regex pattern.

Comment: Glad it worked for you. Please also consider [upvoting the answer](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/173399/how-to-upvote-on-stack-overflow) if it turned out useful for you.